# How can I convert a number (of type std::string) to its binary representation in std::vector<bool> in C++ without external libraries?

Tags: c++, types, cryptography, binary

I'm trying to convert a string (like "12345") to its binary representation held in a boolean vector (so it would be `{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1}` but the current attempt only works for string inputs of "0" to "9". For "10" through "19" its off by 2 (example: 10 should be `1,0,1,0` but I get `1,0,0,0`) and for "20" through "29" its off by 2 more (example: 20 should be `1,0,1,0,0` and I get `1,0,0,0,0`).

Here is my current attempt but I'm open to a complete redesign. I'm hoping it's a simple fix (it feels like it should be easy like just...add 2 for every 10?) but there's a caveat thats been ruining everything:

I can't cast the string input to an int or long long because the string will hold a number too large for the built in types (it'll have thousands of digits) and I am trying to do this without any external library like boost.

```
std::vector<bool> stringToBinary(std::string num) {
        std::vector<bool> bin;
        int n = ceil(log2(pow(10, num.size())));
        for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
            int x = num[i] - '0';
            std::vector<bool> bits;
            while (x > 0) {
                bits.push_back(x % 2);
                x /= 2;
            }
            std::reverse(bits.begin(), bits.end());
            int m = bits.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 4 * i - m; j++) {
                bin.push_back(false);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                bin.push_back(bits[j]);
            }
        }
        while (bin.size() > 1 && bin.front() == false) {
            bin.erase(bin.begin());
        }
        return bin;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are asking for this to be done in C++ I presume you are ok usin the C++ libraries. In this case you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::string strNumber = "20";
    int number = atoi(strNumber.c_str());
    std::string s = std::bitset< 64 >(number).to_string(); // string conversion
    std::cout<< s << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

You should be easily be bale to convert the last std::string to a std::vector

Ok with the information provided in your comment here is a revised version where you should be able to get the binary representation of any integer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>


// Multiplies str1 and str2, and prints result.
std::string multiply(std::string num1, std::string num2)
{
    int len1 = num1.size();
    int len2 = num2.size();
    if (len1 == 0 || len2 == 0)
    return "0";
 
    // will keep the result number in vector
    // in reverse order
    std::vector<int> result(len1 + len2, 0);
 
    // Below two indexes are used to find positions
    // in result.
    int i_n1 = 0;
    int i_n2 = 0;
     
    // Go from right to left in num1
    for (int i=len1-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        int carry = 0;
        int n1 = num1[i] - '0';
 
        // To shift position to left after every
        // multiplication of a digit in num2
        i_n2 = 0;
         
        // Go from right to left in num2            
        for (int j=len2-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            // Take current digit of second number
            int n2 = num2[j] - '0';
 
            // Multiply with current digit of first number
            // and add result to previously stored result
            // at current position.
            int sum = n1*n2 + result[i_n1 + i_n2] + carry;
 
            // Carry for next iteration
            carry = sum/10;
 
            // Store result
            result[i_n1 + i_n2] = sum % 10;
 
            i_n2++;
        }
 
        // store carry in next cell
        if (carry > 0)
            result[i_n1 + i_n2] += carry;
 
        // To shift position to left after every
        // multiplication of a digit in num1.
        i_n1++;
    }
 
    // ignore '0's from the right
    int i = result.size() - 1;
    while (i>=0 && result[i] == 0)
    i--;
 
    // If all were '0's - means either both or
    // one of num1 or num2 were '0'
    if (i == -1)
    return "0";
 
    // generate the result string
    std::string s = "";
     
    while (i >= 0)
        s += std::to_string(result[i--]);
 
    return s;
}

// A function to perform division of large numbers
std::string longDivision(std::string number, int divisor)
{
    // As result can be very large store it in string
    std::string ans;
 
    // Find prefix of number that is larger
    // than divisor.
    int idx = 0;
    int temp = number[idx] - '0';
    while (temp < divisor)
        temp = temp * 10 + (number[++idx] - '0');
 
    // Repeatedly divide divisor with temp. After
    // every division, update temp to include one
    // more digit.
    while (number.size() > idx) {
        // Store result in answer i.e. temp / divisor
        ans += (temp / divisor) + '0';
 
        // Take next digit of number
        temp = (temp % divisor) * 10 + number[++idx] - '0';
    }
 
    // If divisor is greater than number
    if (ans.length() == 0)
        return "0";
 
    // else return ans
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    std::string strNumber = "174981883239023362650696299580"; //
    std::vector<bool> boolean;
    while (strNumber.size() > 0 && strNumber[0] != '0')
    {
        std::string temp = longDivision(strNumber, 2);
        if (multiply(temp, "2") == strNumber)    // if this is tre there was no reminder on the division
            {boolean.push_back(0); std::cout << "0";}
        else 
            {boolean.push_back(1);std::cout << "1";}
        strNumber = temp;
    }
    std::cout<< std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "The number you are after: "; 
    for (int i = boolean.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << (int)boolean[i];
    }
    std::cout<< std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some references where I found useful information:

[How to convert a string that represents a decimal number to a string that represents its binary form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605270/how-to-convert-a-string-that-represents-a-decimal-number-to-a-string-that-repres)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-large-number-represented-string/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-numbers-represented-as-strings/

Comment: Yes the built-in c++ libraries are fine, and that works well for numbers that fit into 64 bits, but if I have strNumber = "174981883239023362650696299580" then that overflows the 64 bits and doesn't return the proper 98 bit answer.

Since I will be working with strNumber's that have 3,000+ digits in base 10, I can't know the bit size before hand and sadly bitset doesn't support variable widths

Comment: I have edited my answered to what I think should be an acceptable solution for you.